# Assigning many similar variables in a for loop

Tags: python, loops, variables, for-loop

I'm making a very simple graphical program and am quite new.

```
nums = ["second", "third", "fourth"]
for colours in range(3):
    numString = nums[colours]
    inputWindow.getMouse()
    colour1 = inputBox.getText()
    inputBox.setText("")
    instruction.setText("Please enter the {0} colour: ".format(numString))
```

Where I put 'colour1', I want it to cycle through colour1, colour2, colour3 and colour4 on each iteration (without using a long if statement). Dictionary cannot be used for this particular program.

At the end, the function returns all of these colours inputted from the user. I tried using a list but realised you can't use them for variable names.

Thanks for help.

Edit: Seeing as there's a lot of confusion (which I'm sorry for), I'll try and explain better:
My code up there is kind of strange and comes from nowhere. I'll simplify it:

```
def getInputs():
    for colours in range(3):
        colour1 = userInput()
    return colour1, colour2, colour3, colour4
```

This is basically the gist. I wanna know if there's a way to cycle through the different variables where 'colour1 = userinput()' is (without using dictionary).

Comment: I read about this, but I'm doing a particular assignment and don't think I'm allowed to use dictionary :S

Comment: Ok, what _are_ you allowed to use? I don't want to post an answer, only to be told "sorry, I'm not allowed to use that either"

Comment: @Jett, why would you not be allowed use a dict?

Comment: this example is really confusing, do as @PadraicCunningham advises and use a dictionary

Comment: Pretty much everything except dictionary I think. Oh well.. I'll try use some kind of while loop

Comment: Could you explain (and add to the question) why using a dictionary is not allowed in your case? This seems a rather arbitrary restriction. Is this some kind of homework?

Comment: @Dabrion An assignment from university, yes, we don't "know" about dictionary yet, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing to reflect the new information. The principal thing to keep in mind here is that you can use sequence types (`list`, `dict`, etc.) to collect your results.

```
def get_inputs():
    # a list to collect the inputs
    rval = []

    for colours in range(4):
        # range(4) will walk through [0,1,2,3]

        # this will add to the end of the list
        rval.append(userInput())

    # after the for loop ran four times, there will be four items in the list
    return rval
```

In case you really want to want return a tuple, the last line can be `return tuple(rval)`

Comment: should it be `colours[num*s*[c]] = inputBox.getText()` (emphasis mine)?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try tweaking this around and see if I can get any results.

Comment: I've just edited my OP, the first one has a lot of unnecessary code which shouldn't have been looked at, sorry about that.